# Error while using python udf in Pig

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I am trying to use python udf but it is throwing below error. I am using CDH5.2

```
cat /home/spanda20/pig_data/panda1.py
def get_length(data):
    return len(data)

REGISTER '/home/spanda20/pig_data/panda1.py' USING jython  as my_udf;

grunt>  A = LOAD 'hdfs://itsusmpl00509.jnj.com:8020/user/spanda20/pig_1.dat' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray, id:int);
grunt>  B = FOREACH A GENERATE name, id,my_udf.get_length(name) as name_len;
```

> **2015-01-25 20:47:15,243 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve
>   my_udf.get_length using imports: [, java.lang.,
>   org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]** Details at
>   logfile: /home/spanda20/pig_1422230028021.log

Comment: what is the content in home/spanda20/pig_1422230028021.log

Comment: Can you post the pertinent parts of that logfile?  I was able to run your UDF successfully on HDP 2.2 (Pig 0.14, Hadoop 2.6) with a minimal test set of data.

Comment: ERROR 1070: Could not resolve my_udf.get_length using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse:
<line 14, column 32> Failed to generate logical plan. Nested exception: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070: Could not resolve my_udf.get_length using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

Comment: when you ran the REGISTER command, what was the console response?

Comment: grunt>  REGISTER '/home/spanda20/pig_data/panda1.py' USING jython  as my_udf;
grunt>

Comment: it looks like the register is not working. Try to close the pig client. Open the client again. And run your commands.

Comment: glad it worked, I will post that as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, after a pig **REGISTER** command fails for UDF, you might have to restart the client for PIG to reload the UDF